# Как заставить блоки менять высоту в зависимости от количества контента?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #FAF2D6;
    color: #302E2D;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
  header {
    padding: 30px 60px;
    background: #80C8A0;
  }
  .container {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
  }
    .main-content {
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background: #C9CCC8;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .main-content-1 {
    background: #EC5A45;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer {
    padding: 30px 60px;
    background: #80C8A0;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 860px) {
    .container {
      display: flex;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 859px) {
    .main-content {
      margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>main.sheet</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>Шапка страницы</header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <h2 class="zag-1">Основной контент</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... black tag rome red swed growl trown tron refm th t reident apex dont know at now show must go on top scott town row column flex-direction
                    </p>
                    <p>Llkkjf ioh rtjgh oiriot giothoig huthg oiy hgoyt og hh o oiyt iog gotyh giot ogiyt iy ghioyt goiy hogiy toghtyigh oythg oyt hgouyt goiyt ug yog htyi hiot go8y ogt i goit hygh toyh gout hoyh gtohyogh touy gouyt uog og htyhg ylg to hoo t
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="main-content-1">
                    <h2 class="zag-2">Боковая колонка</h2>
                    <p>Nullam ac imperdiet mi. In efficitur iaculis erat id mattis...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>Подвал страницы</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #FAF2D6;
    color: #302E2D;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
  header {
    padding: 30px 60px;
    background: #80C8A0;
  }
  .container {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
    .main-content {
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background: #C9CCC8;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .main-content-1 {
    background: #EC5A45;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer {
    padding: 30px 60px;
    background: #80C8A0;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 860px) {
    .container {
      display: flex;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 859px) {
    .main-content {
      margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>main.sheet</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>Шапка страницы</header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <h2 class="zag-1">Основной контент</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... black tag rome red swed growl trown tron refm th t reident apex dont know at now show must go on top scott town row column flex-direction
                    </p>
                    <p>Llkkjf ioh rtjgh oiriot giothoig huthg oiy hgoyt og hh o oiyt iog gotyh giot ogiyt iy ghioyt goiy hogiy toghtyigh oythg oyt hgouyt goiyt ug yog htyi hiot go8y ogt i goit hygh toyh gout hoyh gtohyogh touy gouyt uog og htyhg ylg to hoo t
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="main-content-1">
                    <h2 class="zag-2">Боковая колонка</h2>
                    <p>Nullam ac imperdiet mi. In efficitur iaculis erat id mattis...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>Подвал страницы</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помошь! возможно ли создать зависимость высоты одного блока от другого, например: один блок с контентом выходит на 400 пкс высоты, а во втором контента нет. Можно ли подтянуть высоту пустого блока к высоте наполненного. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Так такое поведение вроде изначально было

Comment: нет, просто 2 одинаковых блока по высоте, на них не влияло содеоржимое)